# Possible error when adding objects date atributte in ArcGIS rest

Tags: arcgis-server, rest

I have published in ArcGIS server 10.04 (on win 2008 r2 64 bit + sde + oracle) table ACCESS_LOG on FeatureServer with esriFieldTypeDate field. Then i try to add record with **/addFeatures**:

```
[
  {
    "attributes" : {
      "WHO" : "127.0.0.1",
      "WHEN" : 1320859183000,
      "WHAT" : "topoMap"
    }
  }
]
```

and it work as expected - the record is in rest. But when I change date attribute from "WHEN" to "when" (set it lower case) - i get an error:

```
'features' param is invalid
```

It gets better: when I set all parameters lower case and "WHEN" upper case - the record can be added.

I've tested and encountered this behavior in ArcGIS server 10.2, 10.4 on oracle, postgres, mssql. For the record i check in arcgis sample servers and couldn't reproduce the error.

1. Did you encountered similar problem?
2. Could you in your infrastructure create simple table, try to reproduce the problem and give the feedback?

Comment: Id recommend firing this one at Esri to replicate.  If so, they will log a bug.